# Using recursion to sum up all elements of a list

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm a beginner and I don't know how to do this.

I have a list `L=[1,2,3,100]` and, using recursion, I should get `[0,1,2,3,4,6,...,106]` all possibilities to sum up this elements from L like just `L[1]` and `L[2]`, or `L[0]` and `L[1]`, `L[0]` and `L[1]`, and `L[3]`, etc... 
I try this, but it is not a recursion, is it?

```
def rec(L):
   if not ls:
       return 0
   return ls[0] + listSum(ls[1:])
```

Comment: This seems like homework, make sure you understand what recursion is.  If you don't get your desired result, it should be posted here too, as well as what do you understand of your own code. This helps people to provide answers to your level of knowledge. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your identifiers don't match.  Fix that first:

```
def listSum(ls):
   if not ls:
       return 0
   return ls[0] + listSum(ls[1:])
```

Second at each recursion level, you need to do *two* augmentations: one each with and without the first element.  Something like ...

```
other = listSum(ls[1:])
result = []
for partial_sum in other:
    # append both partial_sum and partial_sum + ls[0] to result

return result
```

Can you take it from there?
If not, search Stack Overflow for questions on "recursion sum to target".  There will be a lot of solutions *very* close to what you need for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Might be helpful

```
def list_sum(list):

    if len(list)==1:
        return(list[0])
    else:
        return list[-1]+l_sum(list[-2::-1])
```